# wymeditor set value?

Tags: jquery, ajax, textarea, wymeditor

I am trying to set the value of wymeditor textarea,
in API documentation, to set or get the value, the code below is given;

```
wym.html("<p>Hello, World.</p>");
```

but this code is not working.

How can I set the value of wymeditor textarea?

thanks.

Comment: If my example code isn't working, then posing your code would be useful. I recommend http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will actually work, assuming that the value of `wym` is the appropriate WYMeditor instance. For example, something like this will work:

```
jQuery('.my-text-area').wymeditor();
myWym = jQuery.wymeditors(0);
myWym.html('<p>initial html</p>');
```

You can also just put the HTML you'd like to start with as the contents of your text area before you initialize wymeditor.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I was trying to set myWym variable to first line of your code.